# compile and run c++ program with own header files in linux

Tags: c++, linux, header-files

This is my first go at making my own header file. I am trying to make a simple Hello World program in C++ on Ubuntu. made 3 files as follows :

//hello.h file

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

//my own code

void hello();

#endif
```

//hello.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.h"

using namespace std;

void hello()
{
    cout << "This line is printed from header.";
}
```

//main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hello.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "in main" << endl << endl;
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried

```
g++ -I /home/Desktop/hello/ -c hello.cpp -o hello.o
```

to compile header file and this command worked.

then, while doing

```
g++ -o main main.cpp
```

I am ending up with following error:

```
/tmp/ccb0DwHP.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `hello()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please suggest whether changes need to be made in any file or in any command in the terminal?

thank you

Comment: You always should compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Options `-c` and `-o` together are not recommended (not to say prohibited). `g++` warns of that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't link to *hello.o* in the command below:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp
```

Try this:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp hello.o
```

Or for such simple program, just issue the command below:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp hello.cpp
```

For ease of use, create a makefile, then you just run make:

```
make
```

A simple makefile:

```
helloprogram: hello.h hello.cpp main.cpp

    g++ -o helloprogram main.cpp hello.cpp

clean:

    rm helloprogram
```

Comment: When we use `iostream` or something like that, we do not compile using `g++ main.cpp iostream.cpp`. Why does that work and not our program?

Comment: @SahilArora No, the standard library is a dependency : shared libraries, that means they are either header only or already compiled (`.so`).

Answer (score 0):

Put hello.h in Path2Hello;

```
g++ -o main -I Path2Hello main.cpp hello.cpp
```

ps: -I option to specify an alternate include directory (for header files).

Answer (score -2):

To compile and run a C language program, you need a C compiler. To setup a C language compiler in your Computer/laptop, there are two ways:

Download a full fledged IDE like Turbo C or Microsoft Visual C++, which comes along with a C language compiler.
Or, you use any text editor to edit the program files and download the C compiler separately.

Comment: for more info refer to this link: https://www.studytonight.com/c/compile-and-run-c-program.php